# Probability of not playing an opponent in a contest with $2^n$ players, from Ross Introduction to Probability

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

In a certain contest, the players are of equal skill
and the probability is $\frac{1}{2}$ that a specified one of
the two contestants will be the victor. In a group
of $2^n$ players, the players are paired off against
each other at random. The $2^{n-1}$ winners are again
paired off randomly, and so on, until a single winner
remains. Consider two specified contestants, $A$
and $B$, and define the events $A_i$, $i\leq n$,$E$ by

$A_i$ : $A$ plays in exactly $i$ contests:

$E$: $A$ and $B$ never play each other.

We have to calculate the probability of $P(A_i)$ and $P(E)$.

Though an elegantly simple approach has been stated here
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2481789/496972 but I wanted to know the flaw in my reasoning

My attempt

$P(A_i)$ is pretty simple. After every elimination round $2^{n-i}$ contestants remain $i=\{0,1,2..n\}$. By symmetry every contestant has an equal chance to make to the $i^{th}$ round. Hence,
$$
P(A_i)= \dfrac{2^{n-i}}{2^n}= \left(\frac{1}{2} \right)^i
$$

If $A$ is eliminated after $i^{th}$ round, he has played  against $i+1$ players. Then the probability of not playing $B$ is same as choosing $i+1$ players out of $2^n- 2$ players. Then,
$$
\begin {align*}
P(E)&= \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} P(E|A_i)P(A_i)\tag{because $A_i$'s are disjoint}\\
&= \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \dfrac{\binom{2^n-2}{i+1} }{\binom{2^n-1}{i+1}}\times \left(\frac{1}{2} \right)^i\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \dfrac{2^n-2-i}{2^n-1} \times \left(\frac{1}{2} \right)^i\\
&=\dfrac{2^n-2}{2^n-1}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\left (\dfrac{1}{2} \right)^i-\frac{1}{2(2^n-1)}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i \left(\frac{1}{2} \right)^{i-1}
\end{align*}
$$

When I simplify this expression, it is not remotely close to $1- \dfrac{1}{2^{n-1}}$ which is the answer. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: @LiKwokKeung , I believe that the game starts with i=0. For that round A plays against (0+1) players. Even if we consider your logic then the probability of A reaching$ i^{th}$ round is just $ (1/2)^{i-1} $. We are just changing the indices here, as I understand. I hope I am not wrong here

Comment: @Karl It's because $n-1$ round is the final if we start with $ i=0$ at the beginning of the tournament . If A reaches the final, he has met all the players that are possible for his games. That way A has the chance of winning $ (1/2)^n$ which looks logical to me .

Comment: In your current formulation you have that $A_0$ is the event of playing against exactly $0$ opponents. This probability must clearly be $0$. For $i=1,\dots,n-1$ it is then correct, that $P(A_i)=(\frac{1}{2})^i$, however for $i=n$ we have $P(A_n)=(\frac{1}{2})^{n-1}$, since the only way that contestant $A$ can reach the final round is by winnning the first $n-1$ rounds, but the result of the final round is irrelavant.

Comment: Yes, this is crucial.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry that I still stick to counting $i$ from $1$ to $n$. This sounds more natural to me.

I think that the calculation is incorrect because

First, in your formula,  $\sum_{i=1}^n P(A_i)=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac {1}{2^i}=1-\frac{1}{2^n} \neq 1 $

It means that something is wrong. Actually $P(A_n)$ should be $\frac {1}{2^{n-1}}$  (See Leander Tilsted Kristensen's comment).

Second, the formula for $P(E|A_i)$ should be $$P(E|A_i)=\frac { 2^n-1 \choose i}{2^n-1 \choose i}=\frac {2^n-1-i}{2^n-1}$$

Accordingly

\begin{align}
P(E) &= \sum_{i=1}^nP(E|A_i)P(A_i) \\
     &= \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}P(E|A_i)P(A_i)+P(E|A_n)P(A_n)  \\   &= \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac {2^n-1-i}{2^n-1}\times \frac{1}{2^i}+ \frac{2^n-1-n}{2^n-1}\times\frac{1}{2^{n-1}} \\
     &= \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{2^i}-\frac{1}{2^n-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{i}{2^i}+ \frac{2^n-1-n}{2^n-1}\times\frac{1}{2^{n-1}} \\
     &= 1- \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}
\end{align}

Note:

We can prove that $$-\frac{1}{2^n-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{i}{2^i}+ \frac{2^n-1-n}{2^n-1}\times\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}=0$$
or equivalently

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{i}{2^i}=\frac {2^n-1-n}{2^{n-1}}$$
as follows:

Let $$S=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{i}{2^i}$$ we have

$$S = \frac{1}{2}+2\left(\frac{1}{2} \right)^2+3\left(\frac{1}{2} \right)^3+ \dots +(n-1)\left(\frac{1}{2} \right)^{n-1} $$

$$\frac{S}{2}= \left(\frac{1}{2} \right)^2+2\left(\frac{1}{2} \right)^3+ \dots +(n-2)\left(\frac{1}{2} \right)^{n-1}+ (n-1)\left(\frac{1}{2} \right)^{n} $$

Hence
$$S-\frac{S}{2}=\frac{1}{2}+\left(\frac{1}{2} \right)^2+ \dots +\left(\frac{1}{2} \right)^{n-1} -
(n-1)\left(\frac{1}{2} \right)^n$$

$$\frac{S}{2}=1-\left(\frac{1}{2} \right)^{n-1}-(n-1)\left(\frac{1}{2} \right)^n$$

$$S=\frac {2^n-1-n}{2^{n-1}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to raise a hornet's nest when a simple solution exists ?

Anyway, rethink your formula considering that if event $E$ has occurred when $i=0$ (round $1$), it can occur in the next round only if both $A$ and $B$ progress to that round

Comment: You can also have a look at a more complex problem. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/378084/a-probability-problem-involving-a-tournament/4093931#4093931